# When would be a good time to ask a professor if he will consider being my PhD advisor?

Tags: phd, advisor

I just started working with this professor, I am beginning to really like the work they are doing in his lab. When do you  think I should ask him if I can do a PhD under his tutelage?

Comment: You said you're working with this professor already ? what (if any) discussions have you had about the prospect of continuing work with him.

Comment: None actually, I spoke with him about available projects. He said he has several open ones and we had a discussion on the project and my probable contribution. He told me that one of his students working on the project currently is graduating very soon. That got me wondering if I should ask him for an available PhD position.

Answer (score 11):

I would tell the professor that you're interested right away, but don't necessarily expect him/her to say yes or no immediately.  Rather than saying "would you advise my Ph.D. research?", just say, "I'm planning to do a Ph.D. and I'm interested in working under your supervision."

You'll probably get a "let's see how this first project turns out", but it will be easier to discuss in the future and the professor will know you are interested.

Answer (score 9):

This depends on how far out you are from starting your PhD (are you a first year undergrad, halfway through a masters or somewhere in between?).

Ideally you should ask as early as possible so that if you are rejected you have time to find someone else. Although the earlier you ask the less likely you are to be accepted, since you may not have shown ability or determination yet. I feel that the best time to ask is probably after the professor has indicated that they like your work.

Comment: Thank you. I am a first year master's student, I have an option of switching to a PhD instead of master's degree. That being said, I know for a fact that the professor has funding and a lot of exciting projects. I don't want to wait too long because he has a number of open projects and I can get started right away.

Comment: By first year undergrad I assume you mean first year grad?